# Azure data factory - convert YYYYDDMMmmHHss to DDMMYYYYHHmmSS

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

how to convert  YYYYDDMMmmHHss to DDMMYYYYmmHHSS  in Azure data factory file name output

Regards
Ravi

Comment: If you think my answer helps you, you could mark it for answer.Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and my source and sink are both csv.
This is my file name: `20201706170905.csv`.

First:create a getMetaData activity like this

[image: getMetaData]

Then:create a copy activity,and the sink dataset filename set like this:

[image: copy]

[image: dataset]

The expression in file name(you can use concat and substring to convert what you want):

```
@concat(substring(activity('Get Metadata1').output.itemName,4,4),substring(activity('Get Metadata1').output.itemName,0,4),substring(activity('Get Metadata1').output.itemName,10,2),substring(activity('Get Metadata1').output.itemName,8,2),substring(activity('Get Metadata1').output.itemName,12,6))
```

Finally: run the pipeline(if you don't need the Original file,you can use delete activity delete it).

Result:

[image: result]

Hope this can help you.